# Symfony CMF. Big picture. Error with controler on login_check step

Tags: symfony, symfony-cmf

Good Day. A have a problem with Symfony CMF.
I went step by step, following the official FAQ, http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html but on step Live Editing, when I login on the page /app_dev.php/demo/login - system redirect my on /app_dev.php/demo/login_check and this page show me an error:

Unable to find the controller for path "/demo/login_check". The route is wrongly configured!

I'm a novice at Symfony CMF, during the previous steps did not have bugs.
I was looking for a lot in Google, but did not find the solution

Answer (score 0):

The route should be loaded via https://github.com/symfony-cmf/standard-edition/blob/1.2/app/config/routing.yml#L3

Can you try running "app/console router:dump" to see if the routes in that file are properly loaded, specifically of there is a "/demo/login_check" route.